# Generate different link per id

Tags: php, mysql

first of all I know there are post like this one, but I cant seem them to work for my project.

Like the title says I want to create multiple pages with on php file.

1. First off all I made the query that I needed for this:

   ```
   SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname), '') AS lastname FROM ps_employee WHERE firstname NOT IN ('Erik','Roy','Kevin','Nop','Raimond','external')
   ```

This part is easy works fine.

2. And now I need my php file I called it staff.php with header and body.

I added this into staff.php:

```
     <?php 

$query = "SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname), '') AS lastname
          FROM expoled.ps_employee
          WHERE firstname NOT IN ('Erik','Roy','Kevin','Nop','Raimond','external');";

        $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while($row0 = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

echo '  <a href="/stats/=id1" class="list-group-item">'.$row0['lastname'].'</a>';

        }
        ?>
```

The result off this is like:

```
║  hans cover  ║
║  dake jhon   ║
║  rot gham    ║
```

But now when I click on them it redirects me to `/stats/=id1` for all the employees I know that I do it wrong but this is for so far I can go.

I did search for `$_GET['action']` ifelse but I messed it up.

I can add all the employees hardcoded but that's not what I want.

Comment: It will be because /stats/ isnt a folder. You will need to use .htaccess to URL rewrite it to be something like `index.php?action=$stuff&id=1`

Comment: Change `href="/stats/=id1` to `href=/stats/=THE_USER_ID`. You'd have to grab it from the database as a field to use it.

Comment: where do you want the link to point to?

Comment: If you want to have a GET-parameter with the id for each name, you have to select the id in the query, then use it instead of `id1`, like `<a href="/stats?id='.$row0['id'].'" ...`. Not sure I understand exactly how you want it.

Comment: I have no access to .htaccess :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
$query = "SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname), '') AS lastname, id
          FROM expoled.ps_employee
          WHERE firstname NOT IN ('Erik','Roy','Kevin','Nop','Raimond','external');";
```

Assuming that you have an id for each user and the field is named id.

Then when you build the links:

```
while($row0 = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){
    echo '  <a href="/stats?=id'.$row0['id'].'" class="list-group-item">'.$row0['lastname'].'</a>';
}
```

I can help you with the first part of the link if you explain a bit better where do you expect the user to be redirected on click.

In my example anyway on the target page you will be able to do

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

and then you can use the user id on your logic.

Comment: the user needs to redirect to its own page like stats?=id3 and there I can make his own charts for him. Thanks for the id part will try it asap

Comment: Last question how can I edit the page of for example /stats/?=id6 because they are empty and I need to fill it up. First I need to call them by Id in my code.

Comment: @Deniz i have no idea of how your target page looks like. Open a new question and post some code if you like to have help. An hint should be to have a look at `isset`

Answer (score 1):

I assume 'id' is the userId in your ps_employee table

```
$query = "SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname), '') AS lastname, id as userId
              FROM expoled.ps_employee
              WHERE firstname NOT IN ('Erik','Roy','Kevin','Nop','Raimond','external');";

        $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        while($row0 = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

echo '  <a href="/stats/'.$row0['userId'].'" class="list-group-item">'.$row0['lastname'].'</a>';

        }
```